# Vertically align symbols in the table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, latex3

I want to create a table that is aligned vertically and horizontally.
I use the following script
How can I vertically align the symbols in the table?
Currently, they are automatically aligned towards each other, and I cannot make them centred.

Edit:
I would like the checkmark and xmark symbols to be vertically and horizontally aligned inside their cells

```
\begin{table}[]
\caption {Caption title} 
\centering
\hspace*{-2.2cm}
\resizebox{1.3\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|l|l|l|l|p{1cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Title}} &
\textbf{A} & 
\textbf{B} & 
\textbf{C} &
\textbf{D} & 
\textbf{E} 
\\ \hline

Some text, in some cases a little paragraph & 
\multicolumn{1}{|M|}{\checkmark} &      
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\xmark} &          
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\checkmark} &  
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\xmark } &  
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{
    Ref number
}   
\\ \hline

\end{tabular}%
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! What do you mean by “horizontally aligned”?

Comment: Hi @egreg, I would like the checkmark and xmark symbols to be vertically and horizontally aligned inside their cells

Comment: Do you mean vertically centered (and horizontally which they already are)?

Comment: yes, exactly @Jasper

Comment: You may do it using specific packages, for instance `tabularray` see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63641583/11829002).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never ever resize tables. And why `1.3\textwidth`? Do you really want that the table sticks out of the page margins?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{This is the caption}\label{label}

\begin{tabular}{
  | m{5cm} | *{4}{w{c}{1em}|} l |
}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Title}} &
\textbf{A} & 
\textbf{B} & 
\textbf{C} &
\textbf{D} & 
\textbf{E} 
\\ \hline

Some text, in some cases a little paragraph & 
\cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \xmark & Ref number
\\ \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may consider avoiding caged tables. In this case, top alignment seems easier and better (table 2).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{This is the caption}\label{label}

\begin{tabular}{
  m{5cm} *{4}{w{c}{1em}} l
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Title} & A & B & C & D & E \\
\midrule

Some text, in some cases a little paragraph & 
\cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \xmark & Ref number
\\
\addlinespace
Some text, in some cases a little paragraph & 
\cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \xmark & Ref number
\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{Another version}

\begin{tabular}{
  p{5cm} *{4}{w{c}{1em}} l
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Title} & A & B & C & D & E \\
\midrule

Some text, in some cases a little paragraph & 
\cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \xmark & Ref number
\\
\addlinespace
Some text, in some cases a little paragraph & 
\cmark & \xmark & \cmark & \xmark & Ref number
\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks for the excellent solution!

Answer (score 0):

With `tabulčarray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand\cmark{\textcolor{teal}{\ding{51}}}% TealCheckMark
\newcommand\xmark{\textcolor{red}{\ding{55}}} % ReadCrossMark
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\newcommand\TN[1]{\TblrNote{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption {Caption title}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[l, m, wd=50mm] *{4}{Q[c, m]} Q[l, m]},
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries}
             }
    \toprule
Title   & A         & B         & C         & D         & E             \\
    \midrule
Some text, in some cases a little paragraph 
        & \cmark    & \xmark    & \cmark    & \xmark    & Ref number    \\
Some text, in some cases a little paragraph
        & \xmark    & \xmark    & \cmark    & \xmark    & Ref number    \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks for the excellent solution!

Comment: thanks also for the nice color you gave to the symbols, much appreciated